# Trouble with size of C5.0 tree in R

Tags: r, cart

I have been working on a fraud detection rules-based system. I have found C5.0 in R to have the most predictive power, but now I am running into an issue. I am only submitting around 12 variables to the model, some of with are integers and some are binary encoding. However, my tree size along the way was become very bloated. Initially I was looking at tree with 30 different splits or so, and now has ballooned to over 200. So, what ways can I explore pruning the C5.0 model in R? The documentation isn't totally clear on how to control this or exactly what the different arguments do, so what parameters can I mess with to try to find less splits with a trade off in accuracy?

Here is my current set up for the tree:

```
fit         = C5.0(x = train_data[,-which(colnames(train_data) == 'fraud')], 
                   y = as.factor(train_data$fraud),
                   model = tree,
                   trial = 15,
                   method = "rpart",
                   rules = FALSE,
                   control = C5.0Control(subset = TRUE, bands = 0, winnow = FALSE,
                                         noGlobalPruning = FALSE, CF = .95, minCases = 2,
                                         fuzzyThreshold = FALSE, sample = 0, 
                                         seed = sample.int(4096, size = 1) - 1L, 
                                         earlyStopping = FALSE, label = "outcome"))
```

And data sample:

```
card_typeL boost_safety_rating unique_device_count network_typeS dist_dev2ba dist_dev2sa dist_bp2ba dist_bp2dev persona_score fraud
2           0                95.1                   1             0           3           3         14          16            25     0
4           0                93.1                   2             0           6           1         14           8            99     0
6           0                93.1                   4             0          19           3         14          11            99     0
7           0                93.1                   4             0          19           3         14          11            99     0
8           0                94.1                   5             0           3           3         14          16            99     0
17          0                74.1                   1             0          12          13        405         413            32     0
```

Any ideas would be very appreciated!! Thanks.

Comment: You are using `minCases = 2` in your C5.0Control.  Try various higher values. It will likely make your tree smaller and can _improve_ the accuracy in cross-validation or on new data.

Comment: Thanks! I have gone down that path and it helped a lot. That and messing with the cost matrix have been a huge help.